# Symfony2 Twig extension |trans filter bug

Tags: php, exception, symfony, twig, translate

recently, i updated my project with composer.
I don't know if the problem is created after or before the update, but in the mistake, this is the update log :

```
  - Removing twig/twig (v1.14.1)
  - Installing twig/twig (v1.14.2)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/symfony (v2.2.9)
  - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.2.10)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing doctrine/dbal (v2.4.0)
  - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.4.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing doctrine/orm (v2.4.0)
  - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.4.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing monolog/monolog (1.6.0)
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.7.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing jms/metadata (1.4.2)
  - Installing jms/metadata (1.5.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing gedmo/doctrine-extensions (v2.3.7)
  - Installing gedmo/doctrine-extensions (v2.3.8)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Updating friendsofsymfony/message-bundle dev-master (d5b40ed => 74f62b0)
    Checking out 74f62b094a37bfcea96e812de0610b96ba412628

  - Updating stfalcon/tinymce-bundle dev-master (4cfe656 => 3205116)
    Checking out 32051165ccb6bde327ec121b3f294d807ceb427e
```

This is the bug :
When a twig template file use a trans extention, i get an error.
exemple, this FOSUserBundle original file do an error :

```
{% block fos_user_content %}
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error|trans }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

    <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" />

    <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />

    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
    <label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}</label>

    <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}" />
</form>
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

but this work perfectly :

```
{% block fos_user_content %}
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error|trans }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

        <label for="username">Nom d'utilisateur :</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" />

        <label for="password">Mot de passe :</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />

        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
        <label for="remember_me">Se souvenir de moi</label>

        <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="connexion" />
    </form>
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

but for draw form, symfony use the trans extension, and i get again an error, this is the error message :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 235.
```

For info, this is the line 235 in "form_div_layout.html.twig" :

```
    <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
```

This error is the same message for the login form with FOSUserBundle and the form rendering.
I have clear the cache, remove cache folder content manually, and i get again this error ...

Anyone have an idea ?